# In Java how do i find the max and min from a text file?

Tags: java, file, max, average, min

@rayryeng has been very helpful to me in my most recent attempt at correcting this file. Since my question has now slightly changed, I've decided to create a new question. I have the following code and I am trying to make it find my maximum and minimum based on the list from the txt file. The text file looks like this:

6

88

77

92

82

84

72

The top number should not be calculated in the sum and average which is why I have put a -6 and -1 in my code (as seen below).

```
    package trials;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class trials2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create new Scanner object to read from the keyboard
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Grab the name of the file
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your data file: ");
    String fileName = in.next();

    // Access the file
    Scanner fileToRead = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    // While there is still stuff in the file...
    double sum = -6;
    int numStudents = -1;
    while (fileToRead.hasNext()) { 
         if (fileToRead.hasNextDouble()) {
             numStudents++;
             sum += fileToRead.nextDouble();
         } else {
                    fileToRead.next();
         }   
     }

   {
            fileToRead.close();
        }
   System.out.println("***Welcome to the Exam Statistics Program!!***");
   System.out.println("Minimum = " + Math.min(sum,sum));
   System.out.println("Maximum = " + Math.max(sum,sum));    
   System.out.println("Average score: " + sum/numStudents);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Number of scores by letter grade: ");
   System.out.println();       
   System.out.println("There are " + numStudents + " scores");
        }
    }
```

I know that the sum,sum is wrong, but I needed something to fill in there so that I would remember to get it filled.

I've already tried searching through these posts as well as many others for help:

[How to find min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534024/how-to-determine-the-max-and-min-values-read-in-from-a-text-file-in-java), [Finding min/max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550817/java-finding-printing-min-max-with-array)

but I continue to get errors. Today is my very first day doing Java, so I have little to no clue where to go from here :-/

## Final changes to code

```
    package trials;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trials2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create new Scanner object to read from the keyboard
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Grab the name of the file
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your data file: ");
    String fileName = in.next();

    // Access the file
    Scanner fileToRead = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    // While there is still stuff in the file...
    double sum = -6;
    int numStudents = -1;
    double maxVal = 0, minVal = 0; //NEW
    boolean bFirstTime = true; //NEW
    double currVal; //NEW
    while (fileToRead.hasNext()) { 
        if (fileToRead.hasNextDouble()) {
            numStudents++;
            currVal = fileToRead.nextDouble(); //NEW

            //NEW
            if (bFirstTime) {
                maxVal = currVal;
                minVal = currVal;
                bFirstTime = false;
            } else {
                maxVal = Math.max(maxVal,currVal);
                minVal = Math.min(minVal, currVal);
            }

            sum += currVal;
        } else {
            fileToRead.next();
        }   
    }
   System.out.println("***Welcome to the Exam Statistics Program!!***");
   System.out.println("Minimum = " + minVal);
   System.out.println("Maximum = " + maxVal);   
   System.out.println("Average score: " + sum/numStudents);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Number of scores by letter grade: ");
   System.out.println();       
   System.out.println("There are " + numStudents + " scores");
}
}
```

Comment: `but I continue to get errors` What errors? Have you tried [stepping through your code](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/)?

Comment: If this really is your first day of Java, then you're doing really well already.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWallace! With the help of all the friendly people on this site, I have been able to make it this far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.min(x,y) returns the minimum of x and y. Math.max(x,y) returns the maximum of x and y. You should create two double variables called maxVal and minVal. In your loop, as you are getting each double value, use Math.min() and Math.max() to compare the current double value to maxVal and minVal. For example:

```
    // While there is still stuff in the file...
    double sum = -6;
    int numStudents = -1;
    double maxVal, minVal; //NEW
    boolean bFirstTime = true; //NEW
    double currVal; //NEW
    while (fileToRead.hasNext()) { 
        if (fileToRead.hasNextDouble()) {
            numStudents++;
            currVal = fileToRead.nextDouble(); //NEW

            //NEW
            if (bFirstTime) {
                maxVal = currVal;
                minVal = currVal;
                bFirstTime = false;
            } else {
                maxVal = Math.max(maxVal,currVal);
                minVal = Math.min(minVal, currVal)
            }

            sum += currVal;
        } else {
            fileToRead.next();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Edwin and Alexandre and @Chloe33. I had to make a few changes to the file to make it work, but it definitely made it much simpler to understand. I will add the file so far at the top of this post (along with the original post to show what I kept/changed :) Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you made the attempt and understood the suggestions we made.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing to an array list and using the collections class.

```
ArrayList<type> list = new ArrayList<type>"();

 while (fileToRead.hasNext()) {
 list.add(fileToRead.nextDouble());
}

 int max = Collections.max(list);
 int min = Collections.min(list);
```

Comment: Could be. I don't read from file inputs much; so thanks for the info!  The collections class has some nifty methods.

Answer (score 0):

How to find min and max:

Have two variables. Call them min and max.

Set min with the biggest number you can find.

If min and max are Integer, then you already have MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE sets.
Set max with the smallest number around.

Then for every number you find, do:

`max = Math.max(max, number);
min = Math.min(min, number);`