# I need to open a text file that contains integers and i need to print out the smallest and lowest numbers in the file

Tags: java

Here is what i've got so far. I dont't know how to print the lowest and highest number to the screen. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

```
BufferedReader openFile;
    try{
        openFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LABEX10.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Could not open file LABEX10.txt");
        System.exit(0);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: sort it and take the end values?

Comment: solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534024/how-to-determine-the-max-and-min-values-read-in-from-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: That's what i don't know how to do. How do i sort it?.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("LABEX10.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    final LongSummaryStatistics summary = lines
            .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
            .summaryStatistics();
    System.out.printf("range [%d .. %d]%n", summary.getMin(), summary.getMax());
}
```

This approach is more modern than the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534024/how-to-determine-the-max-and-min-values-read-in-from-a-text-file-in-java).